# Error in loading laravel web page on macOS

Tags: php, laravel, macos

When I set `localhost:8000/laravel` in a Web browser, this image appear error in laravel permission and error in database calling.

[image]

How do I solve it?

Comment: Do you have the proper permission on your storagefolder?

Comment: I see two issues in the images. 1. Seems you didn't set necessary permission to storage folder. 2. You didn't set the correct database name in the env file. Can you check those 2 things? It also answered well in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/how-to-set-up-file-permissions-for-laravel

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set up file permissions for Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/how-to-set-up-file-permissions-for-laravel)

Comment: try this command:
`php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, it's because you haven't run this command after creating a project:

```
php artisan generate:key
```

This generates an application key in your `.env`, so that it can be used to encrypt your content.

If that doesn't work (which seems to be the case), looks like you tried to query your database with the wrong configurations. In the root directory, there should be a `.env` file with the parameters `DB_DATABASE=laravel`. Edit that to your actual name of your database and fill out other params like the `DB_USERNAME` and `DB_PASSWORD`.

Also, as another person mentioned below, you may want to use `chmod` to change permissions of your Laravel files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have special permissions in your folders, as per the doc:

> Directories within the storage and the bootstrap/cache directories
>   should be writable by your web server or Laravel will not run.

Make sure those are in place.